# Using music videos through YouTube API in an android app

Tags: android, youtube-api

So I am working on an android app, which will stream music videos from YouTube API. I will implement ads in activities other than the one, where YouTube videos will be streaming. Wondering is it legally fine to go with this idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not for seeking out legal advice. Terms of Service for site should be consulted

Answer (score 1):

The [terms](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) should make it quite clear.

> You agree not to use the YouTube API for any of the following
>   commercial uses unless You obtain YouTube's prior written approval:
>
> - the sale of the YouTube API, API Data, YouTube audiovisual content or
>     related services, or access to any of the foregoing;
> - the sale of
>     advertising, sponsorships, or promotions placed on or within the
>     YouTube audiovisual content or player; or
> - the sale of advertising,
>     sponsorships, or promotions on any page of the API Client containing
>     YouTube audiovisual content, unless other content not obtained from
>     YouTube appears on the same page and is of sufficient value to be the
>     basis for such sales.

Comment: So where can I seek for the approval? Their service approval form [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/coming-soon) seems under construction.

Comment: Also I won't implement ads in the activity where the YouTube videos will be streaming. I will implement ads in other activities.(sorry, i didn't mention this in the question :)